# Powershell Start-process create path with space

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pass variable into a $args to create a directory. When I try to pass $d = C:\Call, The script execute successfully but when I try to pass $d = "C:\Call Balance" the script fails. I am not able to create directory with space. Below is the sample piece of code from the project from which I am working on. Please advice.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$d = "C:\Call Balance"
#$args = '-noprofile -command "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "/c","dir""'
#$args = "-noprofile -command ""Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList /c,mkdir,$d"""
$args = "-noprofile -command ""Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList /c,mkdir,""""$d"""""""
$result = (Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $args -NoNewWindow -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
$result
```

Comment: well, for one, using the variable `$args` is problematic as it is a special variable in powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As painful as this seems, you can do:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$d = "C:\Call Balance"

$list = "-noprofile -command ""Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c mkdir """"$d""""'"""

$result = (Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $args -NoNewWindow -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
$result
```

Using the single quotes and passing all of the arguments as one string helps. The way you had it, it would pass the full name to ArgumentList, but it would not maintain the quotes when it passed them on command line to cme.exe. But using 1 argument, with spaces and quotes, gets the quotes all the way to the `mkdir` command

Comment: Hi Godfrey, Yes it is working for me. Thanks for your advice. I have modified my syntax. Below is the argument.   `$list = "-noprofile -command ""Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c ""$tab"" /silent /install ACCEPTEULA=1 ACTIVATIONSERVICE=0 """"""INSTALLDIR=$($spath)"""""" ""/log $tableaulog""'"""`